# Why do I get "weka.attributeSelection.PrincipalComponents: No attributes!" while running WEKA PCA in Java?

Tags: java, weka, pca

I have to make a visualization of a 4 dimension dataset (plus the class attribute). To this purpose, I want to run PCA on the whole dataset. Since I don't have to do any machine learning on the dataset, I don't split it into train and test. The following is the code I've tried to write:

```
PrincipalComponents pc = new PrincipalComponents();
pc.setMaximumAttributeNames(2);
System.out.println(dataset.numAttributes()); // this prints 5
pc.buildEvaluator(dataset); //this row raises the exception
weka.core.Instances datasetR2 = pc.transformedData(dataset);
System.out.println(datasetR2.numAttributes());
```

The command "buildEvaluator" raises the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" weka.core.WekaException:
>   weka.attributeSelection.PrincipalComponents: No attributes!   at
>   weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1201)   at
>   weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1138)   at
>   weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1468)   at
>   weka.attributeSelection.PrincipalComponents.buildAttributeConstructor(PrincipalComponents.java:525)
>     at
>   weka.attributeSelection.PrincipalComponents.buildEvaluator(PrincipalComponents.java:466)
>     at
>   clustering.sperimentation.GoldStandardTest.clusterPrint(GoldStandardTest.java:154)
>     at orchestration.Orchestrator.main(Orchestrator.java:22)

I would expect that datasetR2 should contain the initial dataset transformed into a 2D dataset.

Comment: could you also post the part of the code where `dataset` variable is initialized?